# Lazy loading with wordpress not working in contents added via ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, wordpress, lazy-loading

I am making the pagination working with infinite scroll. But lazy loading is not working in these contents. I am using following ajax function

```
        $.ajax({
            url: nextUrl,
            type: 'get',
            success: function(html){
                newData = $(html).find('div#ajax_pagination');
                $("#ajax_pagination").append(newData); 
                $(html).find('img[data-lazy-src]').each( function() {
                    lazy_load_image( this );
                });
            },
        });
```

It is showing an error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: lazy_load_image is not defined
```

Any ideas?

Comment: sorry to point out the obvious, but... `lazy_load_image` is not defined. That is why it is failing. Most likely it is defined in a scope that this ajax request doesn't have access to.

Comment: @KevinB : it is working on images that are already loaded when the page is loaded. The lazyload js is also included in the page. Please see the link.

Comment: I can't(or more precisely, won't) go to the link, and your question shouldn't require going to another site to see the problem.

Comment: lazy_load_image is defined. YOu can see the function in the lazyload.js file in the page source. The link is for people to see the issue live.

Comment: Right, i'm sure it's defined somewhere, but it is not defined where you are trying to use it. Your code above works if you define the lazy_load_image method above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is defined inside another function in that "lazy_load" file, so it is private to that scope.  Other functions outside that scope cannot call it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I changed the lazy load files js file. that fixed the error. but images are still not appearing.

Comment: I changed it like      $('img[data-lazy-src]').each( function() {
      lazy_load_image( this );
     }); and that fixed the issue. Thank you for the help and the time you took for having a look at the issue.